# scala method vs function partial application

Tags: scala, functional-programming, currying, partially-applied-type

Hereby, I would like to understand the difference between:

```
val aCurriedfunc: Int => String => String = x => y => x + " " + y 
aCurriedfunc (2)
```

and

```
def aCurriedMethod (x:Int) (y: String) = x + " " + y
aCurriedMethod (2) _
```

Indeed why is it that the first case required no "_" but the second case requires it. 
Yes one is a function with a type and the other a method which has no real type in Sscala from what I understood. However this distinction just lead me to a second question.

- Does any of this has something to do with eta expansion?

If yes

- How to distinguish between partially applied function and eta expansion?

Comment: Take a look here first: [Scala currying vs partially applied functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309501/scala-currying-vs-partially-applied-functions)  [and here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650549/using-partial-functions-in-scala-how-does-it-work/8650639#8650639)

Comment: There are no curried methods. The nature of currying and of Scala and its implementation on the JVM mean that only Function may be curried. Partial application can "lift" a method to a function at which time it could become curried (by use of the `curried` method on `FunctionN` for `N` > 1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `_` in `curriedMethod (2) _` asks the compiler to perform eta-expansion. The result of this is a function, afterwards there is no way (or need) to distinguish between a partially applied function and the result of eta expansion.

The separate parameter lists in a method like `curriedMethod` are actually implemented as a single method with all the parameters combined.  Eta-expansion would be needed to make the method into a function anyway, so the partial expansion is implemented by letting the closure created by eta-expansion close over the partially-applied parameters.

Comment: thx for the answer. Although i'm a bit scratching my head to understand <<so the partial expansion is implemented by letting the closure created by eta-expansion close over the partially-applied parameters.>>>

Comment: To put it in code, `curriedMethod (2) _` is syntactic sugar for `x => curriedMethod(2)(x)`.