# What does scala enclosure mean?

Tags: scala, akka

I was looking at ActorLogging [here](http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/akka-2.3/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/event/LoggingReceive.scala.shtml) and came across this syntax:

```
def receive = LoggingReceive {
   case x => ...
}
```

What does this syntax `SomeName { }` mean? I know that in scala `{}` create a block of statements and the last line is assigned the variable. The comments explain it as :

> Wrap a Receive partial function in a logging enclosure

Is there a technical term for it so that I can learn its usage more?
Note: I know what a partial function is. From the comments and answers I understood that LoggingReceive returns a partial function and the syntax of apply.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using partial functions in Scala - how does it work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650549/using-partial-functions-in-scala-how-does-it-work)

Comment: Also read this: [What is the formal difference in Scala between braces and parentheses, and when should they be used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386127/what-is-the-formal-difference-in-scala-between-braces-and-parentheses-and-when)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In akka the `receive` method has to have `Receive` as the result type. So here they're using an object `LoggingReceive` which has an `apply` method defined like this:

```
def apply(r: Receive)(implicit context: ActorContext): Receive = withLabel(null)(r)
```

In Scala we have a syntax sugar construct so instead of calling:

```
LoggingReceive.apply(...)
```

You can simply write:

```
LoggingReceive(...)
```

There's another thing - in Scala we can use `{...}` brackets instead of `(...)` parentheses, so the above expression can be write as:

```
LoggingReceive{...}
```

So at the end they're just simply wrapping the `receive` method with the `apply` method of `LoggingReceive` which calls the `withLabel()` method.

Comment: This actually doesn't explain the feature the original poster looked for. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386127/what-is-the-formal-difference-in-scala-between-braces-and-parentheses-and-when for the real explanation. See the "Function/Partial Function literals with case" section of the answer.